# Add many routes to one service in Kong for different path in the service

Tags: kong

I'm use kong with services and route, need create one service with many routes, some route whith JWT and other not, thomthing similiar to the next table .

```
  | Route         | Route in service | Plugins JWT |
  |---------------|------------------|-------------|          
  |/service1      | /                | True        |  
  |/service1/url1 | /url1            | False       | 
  |/service1/url2 | /url2            | False       |
```

But routes un Kong are very simple, i tried with the option "Strip Path" but send all route:

Without "Strip Path"
"/service1/url1=>/"

With "Strip Path"
"/service1/url1=>/service1/url1"

I Need
"/service1/url1=>/url1"

I only see one soliction, creat one "service" with one "route" for each my the paths and configure  path in the service, ejample.

service1: { host:service1, path:null, route { paths:[/service1 ]}}
service2: { host:service1, path:/url1, route { paths:[/service1/url1 ]}}

But this solution not felling good.

Comment: Have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have ever done this to solve the same problem

service1

1. route1
   /service1-route1    -> /
2. route2
   /service1-route2  -> /
   and you can request as: /service1-route2/{url1}/xxx
3. route3
   /service1-route3  -> /
   and you can request as: /service1-route3/{url2}/xxx

may be it help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serverless post function plugin (https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/) and write custom lua code to strip out the "/service" string from the request

Answer (score 0):

I've used this https://github.com/alexashley/kong-plugin-path-prefix plugin. (It will require `strip_path` to be enabled)